# how to find an element in a vector of vectors

Tags: c++

I want to find string **x** in vector of vectors **v**:

```
std::vector<std::string> vA{"A", "B", "C"};
std::vector<std::string> vB{"D", "E", "F"};

std::string x = "E";
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v{vA, vB};
```

How to use std::find for my case ? Do you have some other ideas ?

**Edit** A result that bool value which indicates that at least one "E" has been found.

I wonder if it is possible to use somehow std::find* this way:

```
std::find*(v.begin(), v.end(), /*lambda with next std::find*/)
```

Comment: do you want to fine one "E" or all of them?

Comment: and if you want one, does it matter which one? And how do you determine that?

Comment: How should the result look like? A bool indicating presence/absence? A pointer to the result? A pair of iterators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
for (auto const &stringVector : v) {
    auto it = std::find(std::begin(stringVector), std::end(stringVector), x);
    if (it != std::end(stringVector)) {
         // do what you want
         break;
    }
}
```

I'd like to make a comment, perhaps as a side-note. Your title asks "How to find an element in a vector of vectors". Your question, however, asks "How to use `std::find` for my case?"

You shouldn't use `std::find` because that's what you're "supposed to do". Use it when it's helpful, and avoid it when its harmful. Start from your data, not from the code.

**EDIT**

To answer your edit, you can use `std::find_if`.

```
using namespace std;

bool find_string(vector<vector<string>> const &v, string const &x) {
    return find_if(begin(v), end(v), [&x] (vector<string> const &stringVector) {
        return find(begin(stringVector), end(stringVector), x) == end(stringVector);
    }) != end(v);
}
```

But this is less readable in my view.

Answer (score 4):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it would be:

```
auto flat_view = v | ranges::view::join;
auto it = ranges::find(flat_view, x);
if (it != end(flat_view)) {
    std::cout << "found\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e34599f521361b5b)

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with just a pointer to the string:

```
std::string* foo(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& v, 
                 const std::string_view needle)
{
    for(const auto& inner : v)
        for(const auto& s : inner)
            if(s == needle) return &s;

    return nullptr;
}
```

---

If you want the iterators:

```
auto foo(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& v, 
         const std::string_view needle)
{
    for(auto oit = std::begin(v); oit != std::end(v); ++oit)
        for(auto it = std::begin(inner); it != std::end(inner); ++it)
            if(*it == needle) return std::make_pair(oit, it);

    return std::make_pair(std::end(v), decltype(v[0].begin()){});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about searching each vector in a loop and then using `std::find`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    

//using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> vA{"A", "B", "C"};
    std::vector<std::string> vB{"D", "E", "F"};

    std::string x = "E";
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v{vA, vB};

    for(auto inner_vec : v){
        auto res = std::find(std::begin(inner_vec), std::end(inner_vec), x);
        if(res != std::end(inner_vec))
            std::cout << *res;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```